# Changing Sidebar In 2023 Theme

Tags: themes

I am using the new 2023 WP theme and I edited the Page Template so that it has a 2 sidebars (3 column) layout.

I have multiple variations of my left and right sidebars.

My question is basic:
How best should I specify which sideber(s) should be displayed on which pages?

I can create a taxonomy with a plugin but how do I specify the sidebar areas?

Answer (score 0):

I got tired of the bugs in php themes hindering my progress, so I switched to the core wordpress theme 2023.

As explained above, I need a 3 column page layout and dynamic sidebars.

Using the 2023 theme that doesn't have a sider bar meant that I need to "dig under the hood" and actually the sidebars using php in the template.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/sidebars/

Which I was ready to do...

Then I found 2 open-source solutions that are simply awesome and benefit anyone paying subscriptions for buggy php themes to simply dynamically place an element on a page:

I am not affiliated with either one of these plugins, but they solve such a as massive problem, that they simply deserve attention:

Block Visibility
https://wordpress.org/plugins/block-visibility/

And..

Conditional Blocks
https://wordpress.org/plugins/conditional-blocks/

As their names imply... I can simply create my sidebar blocks and then conditionally define where they are displayed..

Big kudos to the developers, but this definitely seems like a missing wordpress "core" functionality" rather than a plugin type of solution